# Error in Mutual Authentication SSL

Tags: java, ssl, pki

When I try to establish a TLS channel with mutual authentication between server and client. I am getting the below errors. **The timing between the server and client is exactly same and also the certs are proper in server and client**. What is the cause for this error and what are the possible ways to occur this error?

```
Thread-10, WRITE: TLSv1 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
[Raw write]: length = 6
0000: 14 03 01 00 01 01                                  ......
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 130, 243, 38, 76, 253, 223, 88, 181, 223, 28, 110, 123 }
***
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 16
0000: 14 00 00 0C 82 F3 26 4C   FD DF 58 B5 DF 1C 6E 7B  ......&L..X...n.
Padded plaintext before ENCRYPTION:  len = 48
0000: 14 00 00 0C 82 F3 26 4C   FD DF 58 B5 DF 1C 6E 7B  ......&L..X...n.
0010: F5 44 95 0D 5A D0 8E 6F   40 89 10 2D 00 5F BB CF  .D..Z..o@..-._..
0020: 30 D1 C6 06 0B 0B 0B 0B   0B 0B 0B 0B 0B 0B 0B 0B  0...............
Thread-8, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 48
Thread-8, waiting for close_notify or alert: state 1
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 15 03 01 00 02                                     .....
[Raw read]: length = 2
0000: 02 2E                                              ..
Thread-8, READ: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
Thread-8, RECV TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, certificate_unknown
%% Invalidated:  [Session-4, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
Thread-8, called closeSocket()
Thread-8, Exception while waiting for close javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
Thread-8, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
Thread-8, called close()
Thread-8, called closeInternal(true)
```

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: "certificate unknown" suggests that you are mistaken about believing that "the certs are proper in server and client".  You might want to be more specific about everything you've done with respect to the certificates.